# Not Able to retrive all data from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, nhibernate-hql

In my datasore have one table EFlow and this table have 7000 entries but first 1000 entries  have these fileds :

```
(ID/Name, appliedBy, approved,  childEflowName, completed,  completedApprovers, created_on, dueDate,    eflowDispName,  eflowName,  isResubmitted,  modified_on,    nextApprover,   parentEflowName,    ruleEmailReceivers, ruleNames,  upComingApprovers,  workFlowName,   workFlowVersion,    approvalStateValues)
```

and remaining 6000 entries have these feilds:

```
(ID/Name,   appliedBy,  approvalStateValues,    approved,   childEflowName, completed,  completedApprovers, created_on, draft,  dueDate,    dynamicApprovalStates,  eflowApprovers, eflowDispName,  eflowName,  fieldValues,    isResubmitted,  modified_on,    nextApprover,   parentEflowName,    ruleEmailReceivers, ruleNames,  upComingApprovers,  workFlowName,   workFlowVersion)
```

I have added  draft,dynamicApprovalStates,eflowApprovers and fieldValues this new field.

my problem is when I retrieve data from datastore then I got only first 1000     entries record.

How to retrieve all records?

My query is:

```
List<EFlow> lst =  this.entityManager.createQuery("select  from " + this.clazz.getName() + " i where  i.completed = false and i.approved = false").getResultList();
```

Comment: There was a service limit of 1000 items in a single result set at least in the early days, not sure if that is the case any more - can't find anything pointing out either way..  Have you tried using a cursor. Also have you confirmed that the balance (6000 records) actually meet the criteria of the query.

Comment: Make sure that properties used in your queries are indexed for all entities.

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you are using [JPA](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview). From our docs:

> Warning: We think most developers will have a better experience using
>   the low-level Datastore API, or one of the open-source APIs developed
>   specifically for Datastore, such as Objectify. JPA was designed for
>   use with traditional relational databases, and so has no way to
>   explicitly represent some of the aspects of Datastore that make it
>   different from relational databases, such as entity groups and
>   ancestor queries. This can lead to subtle issues that are difficult to
>   understand and fix.

**However, if you need to keep using JPA:**

As the number of results can be large, you need to handle pagination with your query.

The best way to achieve this is with [cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries?csw=1#Java_Query_cursors).

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPACursorHelper;

...

Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("select  from " + this.clazz.getName() + " i where  i.completed = false and i.approved = false")

Cursor cursor = Cursor.newBuilder().build();
do {
   query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);

   List<EFlow> lst = query.getResultList();

   // ... Do stuff on lst here .. //

   // Get the cursor so you can see if there are more results
   cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(lst);
} while (cursor != null)
```